# TensorFlow Object Detection visualation, grouping objects

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

When using TensorFlow Object Detection on an image with for example a crowd of people, the objects get grouped together like so:

[Imgur link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJhyy.jpg)

This is of course good for some use cases, but I would like to know if there is a way to not group objects together.

Is there a way to lower the threshold, for when objects are grouped together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason for this I believe is that sometimes in the COCO training set, crowds of people are annotated as "person".  Consequently, the detectors also learn to label crowds of people as "person".  There is a way to ignore these "is_crowd" person annotations, but we haven't done this yet.

Comment: Oh, I see. So if I train my own dataset, and don't label crowds as 'person', then it would be able to detect a single people in a crowd, to some extent?

Comment: Hello, Jonathan, was "is_crowd" considered now in the Tensorflow Object Det api? Thanks!